# VSCode xDebug PHP API configuration

Tags: php, api, symfony, visual-studio-code, xdebug

Hi i have problem with configuring xDebug with VSCode i am using OS X

**launch.json**

```
    {
        "name": "Listen for XDebug",
        "type": "php",
        "request": "launch",
        "port": 9000
    },
    {
        "name": "Launch currently open script",
        "type": "php",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}",
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
        "port": 9000,
    }
```

**php.ini**

```
[xDebug]
zend_extension="/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.idekey=SOMEKEY
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
```

**php -v**

```
PHP 7.1.23 (cli) (built: Nov  7 2018 18:20:35) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
with Xdebug v2.5.5, Copyright (c) 2002-2017, by Derick Rethans
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: And what is the problem you're having exactly?

Comment: The problem is that VSCode don't catch lines when I mark them. He just ignore them and I don't know why. Any idea? @rrd

Comment: Collect Xdebug logs. Maybe your VSC does not get Xdebug connection at all. I mean -- Xdebug might be connecting to some another service instead (as you are on Mac and using standard TCP 9000 port). I suggest to use `9001` or some another port number for Xdebug to avoid *possible* issues with php-fpm (quite often it gets installed without you knowing about and it also uses 9000 port)

Comment: OH MY GOD. You had right. I had something on port 9000 probably also php-fpm. Thank you very much you are the best!!!!! I am trying already 3 days fix this problem :D